# SharePoint workflow over 20 mins

Tags: sharepoint

We have a few synchronous workflows that last more than 20 mins.  It looks like the workflow is starting and completing successfully.  But on the workflow settings page it says the workflow is running even after it is completed.  This only happens if the workflow last longer than 20 mins.  It seems like there is a timeout happening somewhere.  But all of our timeouts are set to 60 mins in IIS.  Is there a timeout setting that I am missing?  Where else besides IIS is there a timeout setting?  Or, is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it SharePoint 2010?

**Workflow Timeout:** The timeout setting specifies the amount of time (in minutes) in which a workflow timer job must complete before it is considered to have stopped responding and is forced to stop processing. Jobs that time out are returned to the queue to be reprocessed later. The default timeout period is five minutes.

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn workflow-eventdelivery-timeout -pv "10"
```